# IAM condition to restrict access to a managed zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-dns

Currently Google Cloud DNS does not have the ability to assign access by zone.
So what I am trying to do is create an IAM condition to restrict the user(principal) to a specific managed zone.

I've tried the following conditions:

```
resource.name.extract('/managedZones/{name}').startsWith("my-zone-name")
```

```
resource.name.startsWith("projects/my-project-id/managedZones/my-zone-name")
```

As an alternative strategy I tried using tags with `resource.matchTag` and assigning a matching label to the DNS zones. This also does not appear to work.

DNS isn't listed under https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes so I don't know whether it's a case of IAM not supporting conditions on Cloud DNS or if there is a problem with my expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that IAM conditions do not yet support Cloud DNS per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69719982